# Checking for defined values in subset()

Tags: r

Trying to get a subset of a data frame based on, to borrow from SQL, values that are not null. Trying something like:

```
lately <- subset(data, year > 1997 & myvalue != NA)
```

But that's not right. Any tips, r'sters?

Comment: Data? "Not right" definition?  We're not mind-readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
subset(data, year > 1997 & !is.na(myvalue))
```

should do it. The reason your version doesn't work is that `foo != NA` or `foo == NA` is always `NA` because we don't know what the `NA` datum is. Use `is.na()` to test for `NA` and negate it using `!` if you want "not NA".

E.g.:

```
> dat <- data.frame(year = 1995:2000, myvalue = c(1,3,4,NA,6,10))
> dat
  year myvalue
1 1995       1
2 1996       3
3 1997       4
4 1998      NA
5 1999       6
6 2000      10
> subset(dat, year > 1997 & myvalue != NA)
[1] year    myvalue
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> subset(dat, year > 1997 & !is.na(myvalue))
  year myvalue
5 1999       6
6 2000      10
```

It is instructive to ponder further on why your version doesn't work.

The first parts of the clause returns:

```
> with(dat, year > 1997)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

For the first 3 elements we don't need to do any further checking as they are FALSE, but we need to check the second clause for the final three elements in the example. The second clause returns `NA` for all elements, as discussed above:

```
> with(dat, myvalue != NA)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Hence the combined clause returns:

```
> with(dat, year > 1997 & myvalue != NA)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA    NA
```

which will end up not selecting any rows, and hence the zero-row object returned for your example.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful response.